# PHP foreach loop inside foreach loop accessing variables

Tags: php, curl

I have edited my question. I am trying to loop through each array and use it inside one foreach loop, is this possible?

```
foreach ($exhibitor as $exhibitors)
{
    //Foreach loop of each variable we need
    foreach ($exhibitorsLoop as $i) {
        $names[] = $i['exhibitor']['exhname'];
        $logos[] = $i['exhibitor']['onlinelogo'];
        //Sponsorship level 2-11
        $packages[] = $i['exhibitor']['package'];
        $descriptions[] = $i['exhibitor']['description'];
        $websites[] = $i['exhibitor']['website'];
    }
}
```

How I plan to use it

```
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php $logo ?>" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1 style="margin-top:0;"><?php echo $name; ?></h1>
            <h2><?php echo $website; ?></h2>
        </div>
```

When I print a value, such as print_r($logos), I get all the values. When I write a foreach loop such as

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
 echo $name;
}
```

It also returns the value. But i'm having trouble getting it to return properly in the html block. Do I need to write a foreach loop for each array (names, logos, packages, etc.)?

I have tried a few different array merge methods but nothing gives me the final result I am looking for. I would like to have each exhibitor be looped through and use each key value somewhere in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment makes no sense here:

```
    //sub loop foreach 
    foreach ($jsonLoop as $i) {

    //example data
    $data= $i['value']['subvalue'];

    }
```

Because you are resetting `$data` many times but finally this variable will store only last value. What I think you need instead is just:

```
    //example data
    $data[] = $jsonLoop;
```

And instead of your second part:

```
<?php foreach ($item as $items)
    foreach ($jsonLoop as $i) : ?>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    testing: <?php echo $data ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just output your data collected:

```
    print_r($data);
```

If you need to have formatted html you can extend it but all you need is in your `$data` now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it, I think this works for me:
Inside of the second loop I just get everything

```
    foreach ($exhibitorsLoop as $i) {
      $data[] = $exhibitorsLoop;
    }
```

And then in the HTML I call specifically what I need from the array

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($data as $d) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $d[0]['exhibitor']['exhname']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $d[0]['exhibitor']['onlinelogo']; ?> </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If this isn't the cleanest way let me know but I think this is what I am after.